# Laravel count number of rows in has many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How can I count the number of rows in a has many relationship.

The database is set up like this for example:

```
users:
user_id

files:
id,
name

visitors:
id,
file_id
```

I want to get the collective TOTAL number of visitors for every file that belongs to a certain user.

My current code is this:

```
$visitors = Auth::user()->files()->with('Visitors')->get();
$visitors = $visitors->count('visitor.id');
```

But that only returns the total amount of files, not the total amount of visitors.

Comment: Have you tried `Auth::user()->files()->with('Visitors')->count()`?

Comment: @AmitGarg Yes, again, returns the amount of files belong to the user and not the total amount of visitors.

Comment: Use `hasManyThrough` for this, then simply `$user->visitors()->count()`

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk_deczo_ Work's as expected. Thank you. Can you submit as an answer?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk_deczo_ Also do you know how this is possible for relationships with more than 2 levels?

Comment: It's not possible with builtin methods. However feel free to play around and create your own relation class, that will handle your custom relations. By not possible I mean straighforward way like presented in my answer. There is always a way of achieving that, but depends totally on the relation you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have cascade relations:

`User hasMany File hasMany Visitor`

the easiest way to work with `User` - `Visitor` relation will be `hasManyThrough`:

```
// User model
public function visitors()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('Visitor', 'File');
}
```

Then all you need to get user's all files visitors' count is:

```
$user->visitors()->count();
```